# Want to learn how to pass two values from ajax

Tags: php, ajax

In my current code that is working correctly, I'm able to send this value ($id) to delete a row via AJAX.

```
 <td align='center'><span class='delete' data-id='<?= $id; ?>'>Delete</span></td>
```

However I would like to pass an additional "$userID" value.

Below is my AJAX code.

```
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    // Delete 
                    $('.delete').click(function(){
                        var el = this;

                        // Delete id
                        var id = $(this).data('id');
                        
                        var confirmalert = confirm("Are you sure?");
                        if (confirmalert == true) {
                            // AJAX Request
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'remove.php',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: { id:id },
                                success: function(response){
                    
                                    if(response == 1){
                                        // Remove row from HTML Table
                                        $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
                                        $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800,function(){
                                            $(this).remove();
                                        });
                                    }else{
                                        alert('Invalid ID.');
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: And where does `$userId` come from?

Comment: Comes from session PHP Session

Answer (score 0):

You can read all values data assigned with [jQuery .data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) function.

```js
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
  let id = $(this).data('id');
  let userid = $(this).data('userid'); //ex: data-stack="5" => ('stack')

  console.log(id, userid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="delete" data-id="5" data-userid="12">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td align='center'><span class='delete' data-id='<?= $id; ?>' data-user-id='<?= $userId; ?>'>Delete</span></td>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Delete
    $('.delete').click(function () {
        var el = this;
        // Delete id
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var userId = $(this).data('user-id');
        var confirmalert = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (confirmalert == true) {
            // AJAX Request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'remove.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id: id, userId: userId},
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 1) {
                        // Remove row from HTML Table
                        $(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
                        $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert('Invalid ID.');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I also highly recommend you to do NOT use the `data` (sometimes `data` has bug) of jQuery. You rather use [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Delete
    $('.delete').click(function () {
        var el = this;
        // Delete id
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var userId = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
        var confirmalert = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (confirmalert == true) {
            // AJAX Request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'remove.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id: id, userId: userId},
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 1) {
                        // Remove row from HTML Table
                        $(el).closest('tr').css('background', 'tomato');
                        $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert('Invalid ID.');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a quick note that defining an object like this `{id: id, userId: userId}` is redundant. When keys equal variable names, it's sufficient to just do this: `{id, userId}`.

Comment: doesn't `.prop(` supercede `.attr(`?